# NuGet packages project dependencies as nuget dependencies

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2017, dependencies, nuget

I have 3 class library projects (all .NET Standard 2.0) that are all in the same solution. I want to package them into a single nuget and use the code in other repos.

However, when I package them into a NuGet package two of them are added as a nuget dependency to the third one, instead of being directly referenced as dlls.

Here is an example of my setup.

The 3 projects - **A**.csproj, **B**.csproj, **C**.csproj (All Class Libraries, All .NET Standard 2.0)

**A** is set as a startup project and references **B** and **C**

**B** has a reference to **C**

**C** has no references to the other two (it only references 2 3rd party nugets)

When I package my solution into a nuget package, the nuspec file has a `<dependencies>` group that has all nuget references from my project (*correct*) along with 2 dependencies for projects **B** and **C** with versions 1.0.0 (*incorrect*)

I am not sure what is causing nuget to behave like this (I imagine its by design) but I cannot wrap my head around to fix the issue.

What I want is for projects **B** and **C** to be packaged as DLLs to project **A** and not as seprate packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not sure what is causing nuget to behave like this (I imagine it's
> by design) but I cannot wrap my head around to fix the issue.

Yes, this behavior is by design. When we pack the `.net core`/`.NET Standard`, the `PrivateAssets` metadata tags control whether dependency assets flow to the parent project. If the value is set to `All`, these dependency assets would not flow to the parent project. In other words, projects B and C will not be added to the package as dependencies.

Check [Controlling dependency assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) for more info.

> What I want is for projects B and C to be packaged as DLLs to project A and not as separate packages.

Just like what I said in the first question, we could use `PrivateAssets` metadata tags to control whether dependency assets flow to the parent project, but the `PrivateAssets` metadata tags do not package project B and C as project A DLLs.

If you want projects B and C to be packaged as DLLs to project A and not as separate packages, we need to use a `.nuspec` file to include them manually.

The `.nuspec` would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>TestDemo</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Tester</authors>
    <owners>Tester</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>TestDemo</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.    </releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\debug\projectA.dll" target="lib\.netstand2.0" />
    <file src="<Path>\projectB.dll" target="lib\.netstand2.0" />
    <file src="<Path>\projectC.dll" target="lib\.netstand2.0" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Check [this thread](http://Create%20nuget%20package%20from%20dlls) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the version for dependencies in `.nuspec` manually/ or through some pre/post build command/script. If you need to do this for a lot of projects then I'll suggest to write a script and run on pre/post build event.

The `.nuspec` can not detect the version for dependencies itself.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want the package to have a version in the first place. I don't want the package there. I want them to be included as dll references to the original and leave at that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to generate the DLLs to B and C, then copy them into a resource folder for A which is referenced in A's nuspec file. That is, you are only packaging A, which happens to include DLLs for B and C, so the build of B and C, and adding of there DLLs to A, should happen separately **before** the packaging of A.