# Dependencies version for NuGet generated incorrect in Azure pipeline of .NET Framework Project

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, nuget

In my Azure pipeline I am creating a NuGet package for a .Net Framework project. The NuGet package is versioned correctly using the gitversion tool that modifies the GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs file. This GloablAssembly file is used to version the Nuget Package and DLLs generated as output.

The Problem I am facing is that when I pack a Project let's call it **A that has Project Dependency on B the project dependencies get included in the Nuspec file of the generated NuGet but the version being mentioned in the Nuspec file is incorrect**. It is important to remember that the NuGet,Dlls etc are getting the correct version but the Dependency defined in Nuspec file is getting a wrong version.

I get this issue only on Azure Pipeline but if I locally pack the NuGet the dependency version gets correctly generated.
On Azure pipeline I am using Nuget version 4.9.4.

I hope at the time of packing the version of DLL should be picked from GloabalAssembly file.

MY build Pipeline

```
- powershell: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)\GitVersion.CommandLine.${{ parameters.gitVersionVersion }}\tools\GitVersion.exe $(Build.SourcesDirectory) /output buildserver /nofetch /updateassemblyinfo $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\source\global\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs 
  displayName: GitVersion to update the Assembly file

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: "NuGet Restore"
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: NuGet.config

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: ".NET build"
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.csproj'
    vsVersion: '15.0'
    configuration: 'Release'
    restoreNugetPackages: false

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: "Nuget pack"
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: source/ProjectB/ProjectB.csproj
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: CI_Version
    arguments: --no-build
    nobuild: true
    packDirectory: $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\sdk
    includeReferencedProjects: True
```

The above Pipeline creates the nuget for Project B that has Project Dependency on Project A ie added Project A as Project Reference to Project B. I also create a Nuget for Project A so want to Pack Project A as dependency mentioned in Nuspec file of Project B.

If I check the NuGet package of Project B the Nuspec File looks as below.
[image]
The Project A version mentioned is 1.0.0 but it should have been 2.1.0 as the one for B.
If I do it on my local machine following the belo steps
- Modifying the GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs manually (no Git version required here)
- creating a nuget package by command

```
nuget pack .\source\ProjectB.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -NonInteractive -OutputDirectory nuget-package -version 2.1.0 -Verbosity Detailed
```

- NuGet package generated with version 2.1.0. DLL for Project B packed has version 2.1.0. The dependency of Project B mentioned in Nuspec file has version 2.1.0

Comment: Can you please provide more information on how your project is put together? Is your NuGet package been generated from a Microsoft.NET.SDK project type? (.csproj file will state so at the top of the file `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">...</project>`. Are you packaging your project from a .nuspec file you created yourself or is it being auto-generated.

Comment: The Project Dependencies are being added as Project Reference and that ultimately gets added in csproj. I am not packing it from Nuspec . I am packing .csproj with -IncludeProjectReference that also packs the dependency and updates the .nuspec with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52814421/nuget-packages-project-dependencies-as-nuget-dependencies is similar(Not Exactly). I just want the correct version to be present in my Nuspec file.

Comment: Have you taken the `msbuild.exe` command your Azure DevOps pipeline task is executing (it will be spitted out in the task log output) and executed it on your local machine (replacing the build server specific file paths with ones that are on your local machine)? That's the best way to figure out why it "works on my machine" vs server. Update your question with the result of you've found by doing so, showing the commands its executing on the server vs when you execute it yourself.

Comment: `-IncludeProjectReference` is a nuget.exe only argument, and is not related to making project references into dependencies. `nuget.exe pack` only supports `packages.config`, not `PackageReference`. The supported way to pack projects using `PackageReference` is to use `dotnet pack` or `msbuild -t:pack`. However, these methods only use MSBuild properties to determine version numbers. It does not analyze the compiled binary. Therefore, you'll get best results if you can make gitversion update the version number in your csproj files.

Comment: Please share you build pipeline task here and how did you pack the nuget package on your local? BTW, what you mean `GlobalAssembly.Info.cs` is `GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs`? Would you share us some images about your question? The description of your problem makes it difficult for us to understand what you are doing.

Comment: I have added the details . Hope it explains my point. Thanks everybody for the help

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Hope the information added make sense and may be it is possible for you to help me get out of this situation. Thanks in advance